# Get Second duplicate Record

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am getting after doing joins as ::

```
CompanyID            EmpID                Emp_no      Location
-------------------- -------------------- -------------  -------------
1                    24                   100543         First.png
1                    24                   100543         Second.png
```

I want to select second Record i.e. Second.png by using `CASE WHEN` in select query.

Comment: What determines first and second?

Comment: Those are png files that I have to find

Comment: So you want all rows with 'Second' in its location?

Comment: Show your  sql query .

Answer (score 0):

Check this out.

```
declare @t table(CompanyID int, empid int, emp_no varchar(50), location varchar(100))    
insert into @t values (1,24,100543,'First.png'),(1,24,100543,'Second.png'),(1,25,100544,'Second.png'),(1,25,100544,'First.png')

select * from 
(
select 
    ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by companyid, empid order by companyid, empid ) rowno,  * 
from 
    @t
) a where rowno = 2 --and empid = 24  --here you can give empid to get particular employee detail
```

In case you want to get multiple empid's second entry in single select statement.

```
declare @t table(CompanyID int, empid int, emp_no varchar(50), location varchar(100))

insert into @t values (1,24,100543,'First.png'),(1,24,100543,'Second.png'),(1,25,100544,'Second.png'),(1,25,100544,'First.png')
,(1,26,100545,'First.png')

;with cte as
(
    select 
        *
    from 
    (
    select 
        ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by  empid order by empid ) rowno,  * 
    from 
        @t
    ) a 
),
cte1 as (
    select
            *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY empid ORDER BY rowno DESC) as RN
        from cte
)
select * from cte1 where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write as:

```
;WITH CTE as
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY CompanyID,EmpID,Emp_no ORDER BY (SELECT 1))
       AS rownum,CompanyID,EmpID,Emp_no,Location
       FROM (SELECT * FROM @Test ) AS T
),CTE1 as
(
SELECT MAX(rownum) AS maxrownum, 
       CompanyID,
       EmpID,
       Emp_no      
FROM CTE
GROUP BY CompanyID,EmpID,Emp_no
)
SELECT T.CompanyID,T.EmpID,T.Emp_no,T.Location
FROM CTE T
JOIN CTE1 T1 ON T.CompanyID = T1.CompanyID
             AND T.EmpID = T1.EmpID
             AND T.Emp_no = T1.Emp_no
             AND T.rownum = T1.maxrownum
```

Explanation:

1. As there's no column like primary key through which  we can identify
   which row comes first you can write `SELECT 1` in partition window.
2. Once you get rownumber for each combination of CompanyID,EmpID and Emp_no   you can use second CTE to get the maxrow for each
   combination
3. Just collect the data from the table for all rows with maxrownumbers

Hope this helps:)